# How to make(or idea) multiple language on dynamic menu on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to make dynamic menu on Laravel. The menu level will be stored in database. But my problem is that, these menus must able to switch to other language. So I'm not sure the `laravel-localization` is capable?. Below is my desire table.

```
menuid       languageA(English)          languageB            languageC
1             menuname1                   www                  xxx
2             menuname2                   yyy                  zzz
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love [**Spatie**](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable) idea.

This package contains a trait to make Eloquent models translatable. Translations are stored as json. There is no extra table needed to hold them.

#### Table

```
id       name
1        {'en' => 'Home', 'id' => 'Beranda'}
2        {'en' => 'About', 'id' => 'Tentang'}
```

#### Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;

class Menu extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['name'];
}
```

#### Creating models

You can immediately set translations when creating a model. Here's an example:

```
$menu = Menu::create([
   'name' => [
      'en' => 'About',
      'id' => 'Tentang'
   ],
]);
```

#### Getting a translation

The easiest way to get a translation for the current locale is to just get the property for the translated attribute.

```
$menu->name;
```

Comment: Dear Wahyu Kristianto, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways two do that for example you can separate the data for two tables like

```
// Menus
id
link
sort_number
created_at
updated_at

// Menus languages
id
menu_id
title
language
created_at
updated_at
```

And then select them by relation.